# SAS Merge with column filters

Tags: sas

I have the below two datasets and need the thord one as output.

```
ONE                TWO  
-----------        ------------------  
ID                 ID  TAG  VALUE  
1                  1   Y    1000  
2                  2   N    2000  
3

OUTPUT  
------------  
ID  TAG  VALUE  
1   Y    1000  
2   .    .  
3   .    .
```

The merge should happen only if the TAG = 'Y' in TWO dataset.
Also need all the values from ONE dataset.

Can this be done using SAS MERGE?

Comment: You need to show some effort to solve a problem before posting it.

Answer (score 1):

```
data output;
    merge one (in=a)
          two (in=b where=(tag = 'Y'));
    by id;
    if a;
run;
```